# Merge table rows vertically and align text vertically

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, rotating

I want to create a table that looks like this:

[image]

So this is what I already got:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]
    \centering

    \begin{footnotesize}    
    \begin{tabular}{p{0.5cm}p{3cm}p{1.5cm}p{1.5cm}p{1.5cm}p{1.5cm}p{1.5cm}}
        \toprule
          \multicolumn{2}{c}{}
        & \textbf{A}
        & \textbf{B}
        & \textbf{C}
        & \textbf{D}
        & \textbf{E} \\
        \midrule
        \midrule
        \multirow{2}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{Texttexttext}}
        & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
        & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \end{footnotesize}

    \caption{Übersicht über die verfügbaren Trainings- und Testdaten}
    \label{tab:6_tabelle}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

The problem now is that I

1. want to have the rows sizes relative to the height of the first cell
2. all cells should have a vertical alignment
3. cells for A, B and C should have a horizontal alignment

Can anyone give me some hints?

Greets!

Comment: You first requirement is not quite clear to me. What are ‘sizes relative to the height of the first cell’?

Comment: When you compile my code of above then `Texttexttext` doesnt fit the size of the table. Moreover the table doesnt grow according to the largest cell.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this (using pdftex):

```
\newdimen\tstrutdim
\def\tstrut{\lower.3\tstrutdim\vbox to\tstrutdim{}}
\def\crl{\cr\noalign{\hrule}}
\def\rotitem#1{\noalign{\setbox0=\hbox{ #1 }\global\tstrutdim=.5\wd0}
  \ \pdfsave\pdfsetmatrix{0 1 -1 0}\llap{ #1 \kern-.7\tstrutdim}\pdfrestore
}
\vbox{\offinterlineskip \tstrutdim=16pt
\halign{\vrule\quad\hfil#\unskip\hfil\quad\vrule&&%
        \tstrut\quad\hfil#\unskip\hfil\quad\vrule
        \span\crl
 \omit\vrule &        &  A  &  B  &  C  \crl \rotitem{text text text}
             &  X     & 12  & 11  &  1  \cr
             & \multispan4\hrulefill    \cr
             &  Y     &  3  &  5  &  4  \crl
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are two possibilities, usng the `makecell` package, which allows line breaks for the `\rotcell` command:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array, multirow}
\usepackage{rotating, graphicx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\setcellgapes{4pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!h]
    \centering
    \footnotesize\settowidth\rotheadsize{Texttexttext}
\makegapedcells
    \footnotesize
    \begin{tabular}{p{0.5cm}p{3cm}*{5}{p{1.5cm}}}
        \toprule
          \multicolumn{2}{c}{}
        & \textbf{A} & \textbf{B} & \textbf{C} & \textbf{D} & \textbf{E} \\
        \midrule
        \midrule
        & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\[4.5ex]
         \multirow{-2}{*}[7.5ex]{\rotatebox{90}{Texttexttext}}
         & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Übersicht über die verfügbaren Trainings- und Testdaten}
    \label{tab:6_tabelle}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[!h]
    \centering
    \footnotesize\settowidth\rotheadsize{Text text}
\renewcommand\cellalign{rt}
\makegapedcells
    \footnotesize
    \begin{tabular}{ >{\raggedleft}p{0.5cm}p{3cm}*{5}{p{1.5cm}}}
        \toprule
          \multicolumn{2}{c}{}
        & \textbf{A} & \textbf{B} & \textbf{C} & \textbf{D} & \textbf{E} \\
        \midrule
        \midrule
        & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\[2ex]
         \multirowcell{-2}[2.5ex]{\hspace{4ex}\rotcell[c]{\\Text text\\text}}
         & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\%[-3ex]
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Übersicht über die verfügbaren Trainings- und Testdaten}
    \label{tab:6_tabelleA}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In Table 2, how can we vertically align the "text text text" text of the first column to be centered?

Comment: @Urko: I had forgotten this point. Just add `[c]` as an optional argument to `\rotcell`. Please see my updated answer.